# PHP error when trying to integrate facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, html, facebook

I’m new to PHP and tying to set up a page as so users can login using Facebook PHP SDK and JavaScript SDK. I keep getting the fallowing error and I don’t seem to be able to find a solution. 
I saw a similar post in here but I couldn’t give solution to the error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/9/d321009915/htdocs/kno_login/login.php on line 2

Here is my code:

```
<?php
echo '<div id='fb-root'></div>';

require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'some id';
$config['secret'] = 'something here';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
?>


<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '293441190799565', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//www.reyesmotion.com/kno_login/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.

  Learn more about options for the login button plugin:
  /docs/reference/plugins/login/ -->

<?php
echo '<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the outer single quotes to double

```
echo "<div id='fb-root'></div>";
```

Comment: OK thanks. I just did but now I get a different error on a different file. (facebook.php) :/ btw should I also change single quotes to double on last echo at the bottom of my code? When I do I get an error on that line. Thank you...

Comment: nope those are fine. actually the problem was that you were terminating it at the second single quote '<div id='* here the string is terminated so the next part fb-root is an invalid token. when u must use quotes inside quotes, try to make them different quotes or escape them using \ i.e '<div id=\'fb-root\'></div>'

Comment: Oh, It makes sense now. Thanks a lot!